# How to deserialize byte array blocks without putting into one big array

Tags: java, serialization, stream

I have a client and server communicating via Spring remoting (using Java Serialization) over a proprietary messaging system. My server returns large objects so my Spring remoting implementation splits the serialized object byte array into blocks, and sends multiple messages. The client waits for all the response messages for a given request and eventually calls the method below to the deserialize the byte arrays into the resultant object.

```
protected Object deserialize(List<byte[]> blocks) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(blocks.size() * blockSize);
        for (byte[] b : blocks) {
            os.write(b, 0, b.length);
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream objInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        return objInputStream.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. However, its very memory heavy. Assuming an object in memory is very roughly the same size as its serialized byte array in memory, I end up with something like 3 times the size of my object in memory:

1. the `List<byte[]>` containing the blocks
2. the `ByteArrayOutputStream` containing concatenated byte array (and possibly another because `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` copies the array).
3. the resulting Object

Once this method returns all the arrays can be GC'd, but during this method call there's a big spike in memory usage.

So, to my question: Is there a way that I can create a blocking byte input stream that I can append the byte arrays to as I receive them? ObjectOutputStream would (in a separate thread) read available bytes, then block until more bytes were written, and continue until the object was fully deserialized. In this way, I don't ever have to have the full concatenated byte array in memory. None of the standard stream implementations seem to fit, I can't see how I'd use NIO to do this, and I'd rather not write my own stream implementation if there's one out there that would suffice.

Many thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement your own input stream to lessen the array overhead

```
protected Object deserialize(final List<byte[]> blocks) {
    try {
       ObjectInputStream objInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(InputStream(){
            Iterator<byte[]> it=blocks.iterator();
            byte[] curr;
            int ind;
            public int read(){
                if(curr==null||curr.length==ind){
                    if(!it.hasNext())return -1;//or use a blocking queue and pop
                    curr=it.next();
                    ind=0;
                }
                return curr[ind++];
            }
        });
        return objInputStream.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

ofcourse you'll should also override `read(byte[],int,int)` as well for efficiency but this will work if a tad slowly

**Or** you can use the [`PipedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and [`PipedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) combo for what you really want. The input stream will block until it has something to read

Comment: +1 You should do this, but please don't do it as an anonymous inner class. :)

Comment: I just slapped something together a static nested or even a full class is better

Comment: I suspected that, it was just a word of advice for the OP, somewhat clumsily worded.

Comment: @ratchetfreak `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` are perfect for what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, below is my new (test) implementation of a Client that deserializes blocks from the server as they come into an object, using the Piped streams as @rachetfreak suggested. Thanks!

```
public static class Client implements Runnable {
    private final PipedInputStream deserializationInputStream = new PipedInputStream(BLOCK_SIZE);
    private final PipedOutputStream deserializationOutputStream;

    public Client() throws IOException {
        deserializationOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(deserializationInputStream);
    }

    /** Called by messaging system when a message is received */
    public void onReceive(byte[] block) throws Exception {
        deserializationOutputStream.write(block);
    }

    public Object readObject() throws Exception {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(deserializationInputStream);
        Object readObject = objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectInputStream.close();
        return readObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Object readObject = readObject();
            System.out.println("read: " + readObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```